# Group By, Take First with a vale from second

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that I generate from a view in my database. I want to cast the results to their own class using linq and c#. I want to group by id and then select all values from the first of the groupings but also select one value from the second entity in the grouping.

For example

### Id   Name Score1 Score2

- 1    Jack 10      11
- 1    Jill 10      11

I want to be able to group by Id, select score 1 and 2 from the first record (they will always be the same) but also select the name jack and jill.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: So you just want to select the first two records from each groupby, correct?

Comment: Yes there will only ever be two when group. I pretty much want to merge the two records but take both Name values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make it easy and group by everything but name? This should be no problem if what you say is true, the scores are the same across the ids.

```
var result = from user in users
    group user by new {user.Id, user.Score1, user.Score2}
    into groupedUsers
    select new { groupedUsers.Key.Id, groupedUsers.Key.Score1, groupedUsers.Key.Score2, Names = groupedUsers.Select(x => x.Name)};
```

This is the assumption that you are grouping all records on id with the following model, not just the first 2 encountered records that have the same id.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Score2 { get; set; }
    public int Score1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I will try this now

Comment: This works perfectly. Though the names are stored in an array like this?

http://i.imgur.com/rNfKZrN.png

Comment: @BadDub - Yes but you can do whatever you want with the names. You never specified, just that you wanted them grouped so names = IEnumerable<string> object.

Comment: Oh so these are just strings? Thought they were an array of characters. This is great then. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Doing .select instead of selectmany does the job. Thank you very much!